# El navegador toma el CSS de Bootstrap y no el que he creado, en la etiqueta a

Tags: html, css

Me preguntaba si podrían ayudarme a encontrar un error que esta afectando a la página web que estoy desarrollando.

He creado un navegador con etiquetas `<li>` donde introduje el texto con la etiqueta `<a>`. Después agregué CSS que ponía el texto en blanco y que al pasar el cursor pasara a oscurecerse.

Cuando decidí copiar CSS de una página externa Bootstrap 5 empezó a modificarme el código en la parte del navegador, concretamente en la etiqueta `<a>` cambiando el color al pasar el cursor en azul.

Llevo una temporada buscando dónde está la parte que está modificando el código, pero no consigo encontrarlo por más que quito y borro cosas.

Obviamente quiero mantener el CSS de Bootstrap, ya que esta pestaña se basa casi únicamente en torno a eso.

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<!--Idioma-->
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!--Nombre de la web-->
    <title>HOLANDA</title>
    <!--Autor-->
    <meta name="author" content="Carolina" />
    <!--Descripción-->
    <meta name="description" content="Página Web sobre Holanda" />
    <!--Adapta la página web a otras plataformas-->
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"
    />
    <!--Palabras clave-->
    <meta name="keywords" content="Holanda, Inicio, Portal web, Índice" />
    <!--Bloquear rastreadores-->
    <meta name="robots" content="index" />
    <!-- Especificar la codificación de caracteres -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <!--Imagen del de la página web-->
    <!--Imagen favicon 16x16 -->
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="Favicon"
      href="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Ffavicon.ico?v=1634125626655"
      sizes="16x16"
    />

    <!--Imagen favicon 32x32 -->
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="Favicon"
      href="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Ffavicon.ico?v=1634125626655"
      sizes="32x32"
    />

    <!--Imagen favicon 64x64 -->
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="Favicon"
      href="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Ffavicon.ico?v=1634125626655"
      sizes="64x64"
    />
    <!--CSS externo -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!--Página web getbootstrap-->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/"
    />
    <style>
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
      }

      li {
        float: left;
      }

      li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      li a:hover {
        background-color: #111;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #666;
        background: #F2FFE8;
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-size: 10rem;
        font-size: 1em;
        line-height: 1.5em;
      }

      h3 {
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: 1em;
        margin: 15px 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 1000;
      }
      img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
      #main-content {
        background: white;
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }

      #main-content header,
      #main-content .content {
        padding: 20px;
      }
      #main-footer {
        background: #333;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-top: 40px;
      }
      #main-footer p {
        margin: 0;
      }

      #main-footer a {
        color: white;
      }
      #logotipo {
        margin: -5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!------ Esta pagina contien CSS externo ----->
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <!--Barra de navegación-->
          <li>
            <!--Logotipo + título-->
            <div>
              <a
                href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Inicio.html"
                style="background-color:#7E3323;"
              >
                <img
                  id="logotipo"
                  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2F616435.png?v=1634143591506"
                  width="27"
                  height="20"
                  alt="logotipo"
                />&nbsp; INICIO</a
              ><!-- &nbsp; mantiene separados la imagen del texto--->
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Holanda.html"
              >HOLANDA</a
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Tradiciones.html"
              >TRADICIONES</a
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Gastronomia.html"
              >GASTRONOMÍA</a
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Lugares.html"
              >LUGARES</a
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Formulario.html"
              >¿QUÉ SABES DE HOLANDA?</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <section id="main-content">
        <img
          src="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Frsz_1boudewijn-huysmans-hx_ygeb2evi-unsplash.jpg?v=1636549628999"
          alt="Portada"
        />
      </section>
      <!--Título de portada de la página web-->
      <h3>
        LUGARES
      </h3>
      <hr />
      <!-------------------------------------------------------------->
      <center>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <!-- Lo que hace que esten una al lado de la otra -->
            <div class="col mt-5">
              <!-- Lo que hace que esten separadas-->
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; ">
                <!--Primera tarjeta-->
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/55467325-304b-4388-a62a-5da1b2df9e7f%2Frsz_1alwin-kroon-kxqyfiin-qy-unsplash.jpg?v=1634037122843"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="Molinos en un campo al lado del río"
                />
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Molinos de viento de Kinderdijk</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    Estos 19 preciosos molinos, declarados Patrimonio de la
                    Humanidad, forman la mayor concentración de antiguos molinos
                    de viento de los Países Bajos.
                  </p>
                  <center>
                    <a
                      href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WWj5QkmFlg"
                      target="_blank"
                    >
                      <input type="button" class="button" value="Ver video" />
                    </a>
                  </center>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!------------------------------------------------------------------>

            <div class="col mt-5">
              <!-- Lo que hace que esten separadas-->
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <!--Segunda tarjeta-->
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/55467325-304b-4388-a62a-5da1b2df9e7f%2Frsz_kira-laktionov-brdkh3ajan8-unsplash.jpg?v=1634038614193"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="Faro en un campo"
                />
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Las Islas Frisias</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    Las cinco Islas Frisias holandesas (Texel, Terschelling,
                    Ameland, Vlieland y Schiermonnikoog), forman uno de los
                    paisajes más desconocidos y más increíbles que ver en
                    Holanda.
                  </p>
                  <center>
                    <a
                      href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_W202S229g"
                      target="_blank"
                    >
                      <input type="button" class="button" value="Ver video" />
                    </a>
                  </center>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!------------------------------------------------------------------>
            <div class="col mt-5">
              <!-- Lo que hace que esten separadas-->
              <div class="card " style="width: 18rem; ">
                <!--Tercera tarjeta-->
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/55467325-304b-4388-a62a-5da1b2df9e7f%2Frsz_clemence-taillez-vgpspydnq7e-unsplash.jpg?v=1634038599119"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="Tulipanes naranjas"
                />
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Keukenhof</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    En este gran parque de más de 32 hectáreas, cada primavera
                    florecen más de 7 millones de tulipanes que forman una
                    preciosa paleta de colores todos los años, también puedes
                    encontrar otras flores.
                  </p>
                  <center>
                    <a
                      href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jEXT3lD3OU"
                      target="_blank"
                    >
                      <input type="button" class="button" value="Ver video" />
                    </a>
                  </center>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!------------------------------------------------------------------>
            <div class="col mt-5">
              <!-- Lo que hace que esten separadas-->
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <!--Cuarta tarjeta-->
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/55467325-304b-4388-a62a-5da1b2df9e7f%2Frsz_sven-brandsma-bp4d8nzcsby-unsplash.jpg?v=1634072601360"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="El Museo Municipal de Alkmaar"
                />
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Alkmaar</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    En Alkmaar se celebra cada viernes entre las 10h y las
                    12:30h de la mañana de abril a septiembre y el mercado de
                    queso más famoso. Además del famoso mercado también hay un
                    museo.
                  </p>
                  <center>
                    <a
                      href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqcPPTxIUTA"
                      target="_blank"
                    >
                      <input type="button" class="button" value="Ver video" />
                    </a>
                  </center>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!------------------------------------------------------------------------>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <!-- Lo que hace que esten una al lado de la otra -->
            <div class="col mt-5">
              <!-- Lo que hace que esten separadas-->
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; ">
                <!--Quinta tarjeta-->
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Frsz_1richard-ciraulo-s6hdaa53c04-unsplash.jpg?v=1636653508802"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="Casas en forma de cubos"
                />
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Casas Cubo de Rotterdam</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    Los cubos descansan sobre una base hexagonal donde se
                    encuentra la planta baja de la casa. Piet Bloom diseñó en la
                    década de los 70 estas viviendas con la imagen de un bosque
                    en mente.
                  </p>
                  <center>
                    <a
                      href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVeGO1V3Qe8"
                      target="_blank"
                    >
                      <input type="button" class="button" value="Ver video" />
                    </a>
                  </center>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!------------------------------------------------------------------>

            <div class="col mt-5">
              <!-- Lo que hace que esten separadas-->
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <!--Sexta tarjeta-->
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Frsz_1malcolm-lightbody-zrpnczd5ic0-unsplash.jpg?v=1636653851237"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="Fortaleza en el lago"
                />
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Naarden</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    Este pueblo, a unos pocos kilómetros de distancia de
                    Amsterdam, y se trata de una fortaleza en forma de estrella
                    que se separa del resto del continente por un espectacular
                    foso de agua.
                  </p>
                  <center>
                    <a
                      href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2HCsjN7A-8"
                      target="_blank"
                    >
                      <input type="button" class="button" value="Ver video" />
                    </a>
                  </center>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!------------------------------------------------------------------>
            <div class="col mt-5">
              <!-- Lo que hace que esten separadas-->
              <div class="card " style="width: 18rem; ">
                <!--Septima tarjeta-->
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Frsz_remy-gieling-0byrakbltby-unsplash.jpg?v=1636654103944"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="Parque de atracciones"
                />
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Bosque místico en Efteling</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    Esconde un pueblo de gnomos, papagayos parlantes o la fuente
                    del Rey Rana donde tendras que prepárarte para escuchar
                    todas las historias de los seres mágicos que habitan este
                    parque.
                  </p>
                  <center>
                    <a
                      href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWZ_dHHHUcY"
                      target="_blank"
                    >
                      <input type="button" class="button" value="Ver video" />
                    </a>
                  </center>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!------------------------------------------------------------------>
            <div class="col mt-5 ">
              <!-- Lo que hace que esten separadas-->
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <!--Octaba tarjeta-->
                <img
                  src="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Frsz_zhen-hu-7oy_izy8kdq-unsplash.jpg?v=1636654527748"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="Flores rosas"
                />
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">El Parque Clingendael</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    La propietaria de este parque en uno de sus viajes se trajo
                    consigo los puentes, la casita de madera, esculturas de buda
                    y hasta los faroles de Oriente que aún se conservan casi 100
                    años después.
                  </p>
                  <center>
                    <a
                      href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_I10Bkjbck"
                      target="_blank"
                    >
                      <input type="button" class="button" value="Ver video" />
                    </a>
                  </center>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!------------------------------------------------------------------------>
        <audio autoplay="autoplay">
          <!--Audio automático-->

          <source
            src="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Fyt1s.com%20-%20Ilse%20DeLange%20%20Changes%20official%20video.mp3?v=1636652056815"
            type="audio/mp3"
          />
        </audio>

        <br />
        <hr />
        <br />

        <!--Imagen casa para regreso a la pagina principal -->
        <a href="https://holanda-pagina-web.glitch.me/Inicio.html">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.glitch.me/d760ef3b-44cd-4fa5-b821-4c8708fc2936%2Fhouse-2374925_1280.png?v=1636408413875"
            alt="Imagen de una casa"
            width="50px"
            title="Inicio"
        /></a>
      </center>
    </header>
    <!--Pie de página-->
    <footer id="main-footer">
      <p>&copy; 2021 <a>Carolina Mendoza Guaitoline</a></p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenida/o a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Modifica el título de tu pregunta: "HTML corregir fallo" ¿cuál fallo? Recuerda que el título debe ser descriptivo, para que otras personas puedan entender tu problema rápidamente. Lee [ask].

Comment: Estás sufriendo un problema de [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Te recomiendo que leas el artículo que te enlazo para entender qué es y no sufras el mismo problema más adelante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa !important para tus estilos, de esa forma puedes lograr que se impongan sobre los de Bootstrap.

Por ejemplo:

```
 li a {
    display: block;
    color: white !important;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  li a:hover {
    background-color: #111 !important;
  }
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Ya solucione el problema que tenia ahora ya funciona perfectamente.